# Can't connect to LAN and internet at same time

Tags: network

I can't connect to a local network with ethernet and internet through WiFi at same time on macOS. The normal reordering solutions don't work. Here is the first few lines of routing table:

```
➜ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.100.8.1         UGSc          165        0     en0
default            10.125.32.1        UGScI           8        0     en7
```

The first entry is my WiFi network through which I can normally access internet, and second is the restricted local ethernet connection.

Currently whichever one is set higher in priority works and it seems like I should be able to somehow get it setup to have them both function simultaneously. To clarify, by function I mean I can access intranet sites on ethernet and access regular internet through WiFi.

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 8c:85:90:cd:ac:f9
    inet6 fe80::9b:9439:d9a8:cf6f%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x8
    inet 10.100.10.27 netmask 0xfffff800 broadcast 10.100.15.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=4<VLAN_MTU>
    ether a0:ce:c8:17:94:d3
    inet6 fe80::1c6f:20f:65a0:5374%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x11
    inet 10.125.32.139 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 10.125.35.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

Comment: What is your definition of both function? You should be able to ping both gateways and if they respond to ICMP you would get ping responses. What IP isn’t routing correctly? We will need to see netmasks DHCP replied with or what you override them to be.

Comment: added some more info, will keep trying to see if I can get it to vaguely work how I would like

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by having the wrong subnet masks specified for the networks.

In your case with IP-adresses 10.100.8.1 and 10.125.32.1 you'll probably the subnet mask set to 255.0.0.0 (/8) for both networks - that is incorrect.

Change the subnet masks so they are for example 255.255.0.0 (/16) instead, and you'll be able to route normally.

Remember to only set a default gateway in the subnet associated with the interface you actually want to use as an Internet connection.

Comment: I can't change the gateway or mask without turning of DHCP? these networks are both managed by corporate IT so can't do anything on routers/switches

Comment: You cannot do that from the GUI, no. Although it is possible to achieve through the command line, that is not really how DHCP is supposed to be used. If the WiFI and cabled networks are provided by the same corporate IT, and supposed to be used in this fashion - I would contact them and advise them about the misconfiguration to get it fixed. This will affect all users - Mac and PC. If you cannot do that, the easiest is to switch to a manual setup instead of DHCP.